# Celery: Understanding nodes and current_app.control.inspect().stats()

Tags: python, bash, celery

Celery provides some lovely stats through it's Inspect interface. But it's not especially well documented (yet). Here is what we have:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Inspect.stats

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#worker-statistics

I love what I can see with:

```py
stats = current_app.control.inspect().stats()
```

but the structure is a little mysterious. Much of it is well documented above, but saliently **not** what the top level of this returned dict is. This is an example of what I see:

```py
{
    <node id>: {
        'total': {
            <task name>: 1
        },
        'pid': 1233,
        'clock': '467',
        'pool': {
            'max-concurrency': 8,
            'processes': [1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1240, 1241, 1242],
            'max-tasks-per-child': 'N/A',
            'put-guarded-by-semaphore': False,
            'timeouts': [0, 0],
            'writes': {
                'total': 1,
                'avg': '100.00%',
                'all': '100.00%',
                'raw': '1',
                'strategy': 'fair',
                'inqueues': {
                    'total': 8,
                    'active': 0
                }
            }
        },
        'broker': {
            'hostname': '127.0.0.1',
            'userid': <user id>,
            'virtual_host': <virtual host name>,
            'port': 5672,
            'insist': False,
            'ssl': False,
            'transport': 'amqp',
            'connect_timeout': 4,
            'transport_options': {},
            'login_method': 'AMQPLAIN',
            'uri_prefix': None,
            'heartbeat': 120.0,
            'failover_strategy': 'round-robin',
            'alternates': []
        },
        'prefetch_count': 32,
        'rusage': {
            'utime': 1.271573,
            'stime': 0.171316,
            'maxrss': 59800,
            'ixrss': 0,
            'idrss': 0,
            'isrss': 0,
            'minflt': 60288,
            'majflt': 0,
            'nswap': 0,
            'inblock': 0,
            'oublock': 0,
            'msgsnd': 0,
            'msgrcv': 0,
            'nsignals': 0,
            'nvcsw': 632,
            'nivcsw': 54
        }
    }
}
```

In this structure I am puzzled what  is.

I am running currently in debug mode and I'm starting just one worker with:

```
$ celery worker -A my_app -l INFO
```

and I see one such entry as above. If I start a second worker (in another terminal on the same machine, with the same command) then Is till only see one node in the sats.

I can see the same node id as follows:

```
$ celery -A Library status
<node id>: OK

1 node online.
```

That node id takes the form of 'celery@myhostname'.

Whether I have one worker or two running this tells me I have one node on-line.

A sample pstree:

```
$ pstree -lp 7813
gnome-terminal-(7813)─┬─bash(4319)───[celeryd: celer(9896)─┬─[celeryd: celer(9900)
                      │                                    ├─[celeryd: celer(9901)
                      │                                    ├─[celeryd: celer(9902)
                      │                                    ├─[celeryd: celer(9903)
                      │                                    ├─[celeryd: celer(9904)
                      │                                    ├─[celeryd: celer(9905)
                      │                                    ├─[celeryd: celer(9906)
                      │                                    └─[celeryd: celer(9910)
                      ├─bash(4404)───pstree(10229)
                      └─bash(7820)───[celeryd: celer(9995)─┬─[celeryd: celer(9997)
                                                           ├─[celeryd: celer(9998)
                                                           ├─[celeryd: celer(9999)
                                                           ├─[celeryd: celer(10000)
                                                           ├─[celeryd: celer(10001)
                                                           ├─[celeryd: celer(10002)
                                                           ├─[celeryd: celer(10003)
                                                           └─[celeryd: celer(10004)
```

Where I can clearly see the two workers and their pool processes. But they are one node (not surprisingly).

So what's puzzling me is:

1. what is a node exactly?
2. what does it mean to have more than 1?
3. How do I get more than 1?
4. How can I get the node name(s) programmatically (in Python not at the command line)?

Answer (score 0):

On further reading and research I think I can answer my own question here.

It turns out that Celery nodes are indirectly documented here:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html#celery.bin.multi.MultiTool.MultiParser.Node

In short Celery uses a set of terms that are useful to understand when building a system of distributed work.

- Client - An application the wants to see work done
- Worker - An application that gets the work done

Terms around those that help to plan things include:

- Broker - The means by which Client asks Worker to do work.
- Application - An instance of the Celery class

At this point, take note that the Client, Broker and Worker can all be on different machines, and there can in fact be multiple Clients on different machines and multiple Workers on different machines, as long as they use the same Broker.

It should be not surprise then that the application typical has the Broker configured with a URL. That is all the Applications, in all the Clients and Workers all using the same Broker URL are all using the same Broker.

The Clients send (produce) messages via the broker, requesting tasks to run, the Workers read (consume) those messages.

Now these terms all have a place:

- Execution Pool
- Cluster
- Node

Each Worker can process multiple task at once, by maintaining an execution pool. This pool might be threads, or (by default) it is subprocesses. So a Worker may a number of Pool processes as children.

One of the frustrations (I have) with Celery is that you can communicate liberally with Workers but not with the running tasks in a Worker's Execution Pool (for which reason I am creating a new Task class for interactive tasks, but it's still evolving).

A Node is a just a Worker in a Cluster. In short Node = Worker. A cluster is a number of Workers run in parallel (using `celery multi` as per the document I introduced with). A Cluster is just a convenient way of starting and stopping and managing multiple workers on the same machine.

There may be many Clusters all consuming tasks from the same Broker though and they may be on the same machine (though one would wonder why) or on different machines.

And that is what a Celery Node is ... (in its fullest context).

More importantly the nodes have names defined by default to be `celery<n>@hostname` where  is 1, 2, 3, ... and hostname is the name of the host its running on. They can be configured using `-c` and `--hostname` arguments of `celery multi` and have no particular meaning and I can't find any way of divining them other than to inspect the keys of `current_app.control.inspect().stats()` which reveals one entry per node.

What is not clear still is, whether these stats reliably return stats for nodes in clusters on different machines (running using the same broker and backend). In short how far a call to `current_app.control.inspect().stats()` can see.

If anyone has experience or wisdom there, that remains an open question.